# How to get max scroll height in jScrollPane?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, jscrollpane

jScrollPane is an awesome jQuery plugin that modifies the default browser scroll bars. I am developing a chat application that will use jScrollPane. It works great so far except for the fact that I cannot determine the max scroll height. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
$(function ()
{
    $('#chatPane').jScrollPane();
    var api = $('#chatPane').data('jsp');
    setInterval(function ()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "Home/GetMessage",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (response)
            {
                // This next line is where the issue occurs. I need to check if the current scroll position is equal to the max scroll position. This is to implement the auto scroll if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the chat.
                var atBottom = (api.getContentPane().getContentPositionY() == api.getContentPane().getMaxScrollHeight()??????);
                api.getContentPane().append(response);
                api.reinitialise();
                if (atBottom)
                    api.scrollToBottom();
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

getMaxScrollHeight does not exist. I need some way to determine the max scroll height.

### Edit

I got it to work with the following changes to the ajax success function. But I'd be open to a better way than scrolling to bottom, getting current position, then scrolling back to previous position.

```
            success: function (response)
            {
                var currentPosition = api.getContentPositionY();
                api.scrollToBottom();
                var maxPosition = api.getContentPositionY();
                api.scrollToY(currentPosition);
                var atBottom = (currentPosition == maxPosition);
                api.getContentPane().append(response);
                api.reinitialise();
                if (atBottom)
                    api.scrollToBottom();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution you could try is to simulate a `scrollToBottom()` and then compare the resulting `getContentPositionY()` with the value before the simulation. If it hasn't changed, then the user was already at the bottom, so call `scrollToBottom()` "for real" after appending the response content.

To run the simulation, you might try cloning the original object and then modifying it in memory. See http://api.jquery.com/clone/ for more info. For example:

```
var simulatedPane = $('#chatPane').clone();
simulatedPane.jScrollPane();
var simulatedApi = simulatedPane.data('jsp');
```

Then, in the success() function, use `simulatedApi` for the simulation.

Comment: Interesting idea. How would I simulate a scrollToBottom() though, any ideas?

Comment: I can think of two ways: the first is to create an in-memory Javascript copy that has the same properties as the real object on the page, and run the commands on it. The second way is to store the current scroll position, run the commands against the live object, and then restore the previous scroll position. This may cause the UI to jump, so you'd have to test it out to see if it's usable.

Comment: The second one I can do, but I agree that it would likely cause a UI jump. Could you update your answer with a code sample for creating the in-memory object?

Comment: See my edit. I haven't used jScrollPane before, but I'd expect that you would clone the #chatPane element and build from there.

Comment: Hmmm, I tried cloning it but I must be doing it wrong. There are no visible jumps when I tried it the second way. If you could actually provide a sample of how to clone then I could probably do it. Just never used .clone() before.

Comment: There are no jumps in FF, chrome, or IE, but that doesn't mean it will be that way in all browsers and/or all versions. I'd prefer the clone way if I can get it to work.

Comment: See my edit. Added code sample. Also, if there are no jumps in the major browsers, I wouldn't worry about it. A small flicker may not even be a bad thing, as it notifies the user that a new message has been received.

Answer (score 1):

I see you already have a solution. Another approach might be to add a listener for the `jsp-scroll-y` event:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/events.html

This listener gets passed boolean values for isAtTop and isAtBottom. You could store this in a variable and check the state of the variable before reinitialising the scrollpane.

Longer term, it would be great if you could add a feature request to add some additional methods to the API: `isAtTop`, `isAtBottom`, `isAtLeft` and `isAtRight` - if you add that to the [github issues list](https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/issues) then I will add it when I get a chance.

Comment: This makes much more sense and is not so "hacky". I will add a listener for this event. Also, I will add the issue to github like you asked as these properties would be great additions to the plugin.

Comment: Looks like I jumped the gun on this one. This sounds perfect but it is not. It is very buggy. Every time you append the container that event fires. I've tried all sorts of things but the isAtBottom property doesn't seem to be very reliable. Looks like I'm gonna have to stick with the hack. It was far less code anyway. Thanks though!

Comment: Sorry - it looks like the parameters were the wrong order in the documentation! isAtBottom is the forth parameter. Please see this working example - when you scroll to the bottom it sticks to the bottom: http://www.jsfiddle.net/vitch/NDFy6/